# HTTP-Outbound gateway not showing special characters -encoding breaks

Tags: spring, http, character-encoding, spring-integration

We have a client which uses http-outboundgateway to place REST calls

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="glNewsRequestChannel"
url="${gl.url}" http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
reply-channel="glHeaderEnricher" charset="iso-8859-1">
<int-http:uri-variable name="site_code"
expression="payload" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

When response is fetched and saved logged in a file, it shows some jumbled character -which is basically unable to translate in specific encoding.
I referred SI documentation which mention unless a factory is specified Java URLconnection class is used to place REST call.
To narrow down the issue, I wrote a small Java program and used the URLconnection class directly without using any out of box template or gateway -it successfully fetches and renders all the special character. I tried another standalone app which apache http library and it was also able to fetch the character.
Any configuration which I am missing as part of SI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that we were using wrong message converter -Instead of using String converter if we use byte[], in accordance to bytearraymessageconverter -it works as expected.

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="glNewsRequestChannel" url="${gl.url}" 
    http-method="GET" message-converters="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter" 
    expected-response-type="byte[]" reply-channel="glHeaderEnricher" 
    charset="iso-8859-1">  <int-http:uri-variable name="site_code" 
    expression="payload" /> 
   </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Where byteArrayHttpMessageConverter can be defined as :

```
    <bean id="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
```